# How to decode text using Java?

Tags: java, json, decode, utf, jsonresponse

I am getting a string in JSON response. It contains a dash (`-`), however instead of it, I get some special characters in the string.

I tried to decode it using UTF-8, but without success.

Here is that string:

```
String subject =
```

It contains `Ã¢Â€Â“` in the subject.

How to correctly decode it?

I am using the following Java code from which I get the JSON response:

```
try{

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(WEB_SERVICE_URL);
String AUTHORIZATION_VALUE = "BEARER "+ "KEY"
httpGet.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_KEY,AUTHORIZATION_VALUE);

String responseBody = "";
try(CloseableHttpResponse responseN = HttpClients.createDefault().execute(httpGet)){
responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responseN.getEntity());
}catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
JSONObject jsonObj = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(responseBody.toString());

jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("messages");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}​
```

In json object, for one of the attribute I get encoded string as given below.
Thank you in advance!

UPDATE :-

I modified my code with following line,

```
responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responseN.getEntity(), "utf-8");
```

But luck did not work. However string is replaced from `Ã¢Â€Â“` to `â€“`.

I referred few links to decode further this special character but I did not get success. Any help would be really appreciable. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please show all relevant code.

Comment: The supplier of the JSON string should document somewhere what encoding they are using, especially if it's not UTF-8. Try to ask them or search their documentation.

Comment: @HenrikAastedSørensen I doubt that. A JSON string [**MUST** be in UTF-8](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-8.1).

Comment: That looks like UTF-8 (several bytes for a special non-ASCII char) read as single byte encoding. maybe it was not ASCII minus, `-`,  but an m-dash or n-dash. Maybe somewhere is a  `new String(bytes)` /  `string.getBytes()`. In this case it almost looks like a place holder `<?>`, as m-dash would require two bytes I think. So even fishier. Show some code

Comment: @MCEmperor: That's a good point, but I must say that I have seen my share of systems that don't respect that, and just use whatever encoding is default for the originating system, e.g. 8859-1 or something. :)

Comment: @HenrikAastedSørensen Well, if you are "part of a closed ecosystem", then the RFC allows you to do that. But this indeed looks like incorrect encoding ;-)